# How to creating a HTML table from a dictionary

Tags: python, html

HTML table for booking:

[image: HTML table for booking]

I need to use the dictionary below to create the HTML table shown in the link. The picture shows the final output of what I wanted. The 'X' in the picture shows we have a booking in that time slot and date. I want to use the dictionary to create an HTML table having an 'X' for all the days where booked = True in the dictionary.

I tried looping through the dictionary, but I can't really seem to make it work. Thank you in advance.

```
{datetime.datetime(2022, 6, 20, 0, 0): [{'slot_id': 1, 'booked': False}, {'slot_id': 2, 'booked': False}, {'slot_id': 3, 'booked': False}, {'slot_id': 4, 'booked': False}], datetime.datetime(2022, 6, 21, 0, 0): [{'slot_id': 1, 'booked': False}, {'slot_id': 2, 'booked': False}, {'slot_id': 3, 'booked': False}, {'slot_id': 4, 'booked': False}], datetime.datetime(2022, 6, 22, 0, 0): [{'slot_id': 1, 'booked': True}, {'slot_id': 2, 'booked': False}, {'slot_id': 3, 'booked': False}, {'slot_id': 4, 'booked': False}], datetime.datetime(2022, 6, 23, 0, 0): [{'slot_id': 1, 'booked': False}, {'slot_id': 2, 'booked': False}, {'slot_id': 3, 'booked': True}, {'slot_id': 4, 'booked': False}], datetime.datetime(2022, 6, 24, 0, 0): [{'slot_id': 1, 'booked': False}, {'slot_id': 2, 'booked': False}, {'slot_id': 3, 'booked': False}, {'slot_id': 4, 'booked': False}], datetime.datetime(2022, 6, 25, 0, 0): [{'slot_id': 1, 'booked': False}, {'slot_id': 2, 'booked': False}, {'slot_id': 3, 'booked': False}, {'slot_id': 4, 'booked': False}], datetime.datetime(2022, 6, 26, 0, 0): [{'slot_id': 1, 'booked': False}, {'slot_id': 2, 'booked': False}, {'slot_id': 3, 'booked': False}, {'slot_id': 4, 'booked': False}], datetime.datetime(2022, 6, 27, 0, 0): [{'slot_id': 1, 'booked': False}, {'slot_id': 2, 'booked': False}, {'slot_id': 3, 'booked': False}, {'slot_id': 4, 'booked': False}], datetime.datetime(2022, 6, 28, 0, 0): [{'slot_id': 1, 'booked': False}, {'slot_id': 2, 'booked': False}, {'slot_id': 3, 'booked': False}, {'slot_id': 4, 'booked': False}]
```

I tried to create a 2D array from the dictionary

```
booked_view = []
count = 1
for date, slots in booking_set.items():
   booked_day = []
   for slot in slots:
       booked_day.append(slot['booked'])
   booked_view.append(booked_day)
```

I need a way to create the HTML table this 2D array. I need something like this

```
[["False","False","False","True", "False", "False", "False", "False"],
 ["False", "False","False","False", "False", "False", "False","False"],
 ["False","False","False","False", "False", "False", "False", "False"],
 ["False","False","False","False", "False", "False", "False", "False"]]
```

I tried to loop through the 2D array like so

```
for  i in range(len(booked_view)):
     for j in range(len(booked_view[i])):
```

I just can't seem to make it work

Comment: Show us the loop you tried ..  And what the output of the loop you tried was.

Comment: It looks like you need a JSON parser